# Automatically redirects to another layer

Tags: after-effects

Hai friends I am using After Effect 2017
I need help, am download one free ae template for my study purpose, on the layer panel cp1 (main layer) and cp2 (Duplicate layer), I am trying to change the text in cp2, what I change cp2 text it will automatically change in cp1 can tell me how to fix the issue
(note: when I click cp2 layer it automatically redirects to cp1 layer).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi - add a link to the template

Comment: https://www.videezy.com/after-effects-templates/19299-corporate-presentation-after-effects-template-pack-01

Comment: step1: duplicate the text (07 - Service 02) step2: change the layer name step3: on that layer change the text it automatically affects the layer (07 - Service 02)